# Firebase Functions + Environment variables - Error: The default Firebase app does not exist

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

### Problem

As far I know, Firebase Cloud Functions natively support .env files, without installing any third-party package like dotenv.

I have created a .env file, inside my functions directory:

```
/app

/functions
   .env
   .eslintrc.js
   package.json
   /src
     ...
```

Inside my .env file, I have the following:

```
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=aaaaa
FIREBASE_KEY_ID=bbbbb
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=zzzzz
FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID=ddddd
FIREBASE_AUTH_URI=qqqqqq
FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI=jjjjjj
FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URI=lllllll
FIREBASE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URI=nnnnnnnn
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_URI=mmmmmmm
```

For some reason, when I try to deploy my functions, I get the error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
> The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

---

### Admin SDK initialization

This is how I am initializing the Firebase Admin SDK:

```js
try {
  const googleCloudServiceAccount = require("./credentials");

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(googleCloudServiceAccount),
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_URI,
  });
} catch (err) {
  functions.logger.error(`Error initializing firebase: ${err}`);
}

// Initialize Firebase Services
const auth = admin.auth();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

// Storage Bucket
const storageBucket = storage.bucket(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET_URI);
```

### credentials.js

```js
module.exports = {
  type: "service_account",
  project_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  private_key_id: process.env.FIREBASE_KEY_ID,
  private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  client_id: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID,
  auth_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI,
  token_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI,
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URI,
  client_x509_cert_url: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URI,
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

-Note: **if instead of using .env and a credentials.js file, I just hardcode all my secrets and relative stuff inside a credentials.json file, everything works fine.**

Answer (score 1):

After globally upgrading my `firebase-tools` and avoid using [reserved prefix](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#reserved-names) everything is working as expected!